# vue emit event and receive in parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi i have two component , I get response in one component and need to pass and push in the array of parent component. Below is my code. I have not received response.
In `Userstatuscomponent.vue` I have few methods and whatever response I get there I want to pass this to `UserComponent.vue` and push it in users[] array. I think I have done something wrong. Please help me.
UserComponent.vue

```
<template>
<div>
        <Status v-on:updateStatus="receiveResponse(userData)"></Status >
    <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-body" v-for="user in users.data" >

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template


<script type="application/javascript">
import Status from '../components/UserstatusComponent.vue' 

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
        };
    },
    created() {
        this.getResult();
    },

    components: {
        Filter
    },
    methods: {
        getResult() {
            axios
                .get("/api/result")
                .then(response => {
                   
                        this.users = response.data;
                   
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        },
        receiveResponse(userData){
            this.users =  userData
        },
//HERE I HAVE RECEIVED THE EVENT and update users array
        receiveResponse(user){
            this.users = user
        },
 
    }
};
</script>
Now I have some method in UserStatusComponent and I want to pass the response from this component to UserComponent.vue

UserstatusComponent.vue
<template>
            <div class="">
                        <a
                            @click.prevent="updateOne"
                            >update one</a
                        >
                        <a
                            @click.prevent="updateTwo"
                          
                            >update two</a
                        >
                       
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            
        }
    },
    updateOne() {
            axios
                .get("/api/result", {
                    params: {
                        status: "bad"
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.$emit('updateStatus',response.data);
                });
        },
        updateTwo() {
            axios
                .get("/api/result", {
                    params: {
                        stauts: "good"
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.$emit('updateStatus',response.data);
                });
        },
        
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. 

When you want to pass data through `emit`, in the parent component, you don't have to put parameters in the function.
Here are some code updates(not tested)

`v-on:updateStatus="receiveResponse"`

`updateStatus` function will have parameters, though which is what child component passed through `$emit`.

```
receiveResponse(userData){
  this.users =  userData
}
```

2. 

`<div class="card-body" v-for="user in users.data" >`
There should be iterable in `v-for`. How about `v-for="user in users"`?

Comment: does v-on: here:v-on:updateStatus="receiveResponse" listen the event?

Comment: There is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-sun-jerbv?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: @David, yes. It listens event and obtains data emitted from child component

Answer (score 0):

in `UserComponent` you have repeated the method `receiveResponse`.

And in `UserStatusComponent` you need to wrap up the functions

```
data() { },
methods: {
   updateOne() {...}
   updateTwo() {...} // this one is also repeated method
}
```

*Update with minimum example*

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
    <Status v-on:updateStatus="receiveResponse" />
</template

<script>
import Status from '../components/UserstatusComponent.vue' 

export default {
    components: {
        Status
    },
    methods: {
        receiveResponse(userData){
            /* code */
        },
     }
};
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```
<template>
    <a @click.prevent="updateOne">update one</a>
</template

<script>
export default {
    emits: ['updateStatus'], // This will prevent a warning
    methods: {
        updateOne(){
            this.$emit('updateStatus', data);
        },
     }
};
</script>
```

Comment: hi methods name are different, its now updated. my main question is how to receive event send from one component to another component based on my questions.Thanks

Comment: after that changes, it should be sending the msg, `UserStatusComponent` emits `updateStatus` and its catch with `v-on:updateStatus` and call `receiveResponse()` (which btw you stil have duplicated, one def of `receiveResponse` will do)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply that the event-listener is in camelcase, while it should be in kebab-case (at least when using DOM-Templates). Try it like this:

```
<Status v-on:update-status="receiveResponse(userData)"></Status >
```

In other words: Vue automatically translates the camel-cased *updateStatus* event emit to kebab-cased *update-status*, thus you can emit with camel-case, but can't listen with camel-case. See:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#event-names
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-casing-camelcase-vs-kebab-case

**For VueJS 2 use kebab-case only** (in emit & listener), as VueJS 2 does NOT translate camel- to kebab-case. VueJS 2 will transform any event-listener in the DOM to lower case. More on this:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html